# JPQL query using WHERE column = int

Tags: jpa, jpql

I'm new to using JPQL/JPA and I somehow can't get this working:

```
public List<Bil> hentBiler(int kontor) {
List<Bil> biler = new ArrayList<Bil>(); 
TypedQuery<Bil> query = em.createQuery("SELECT o FROM Bil o WHERE o.kontornr = ?1", Bil.class);
query.setParameter(1, kontor);
}
```

The kontornr column in the database is an integer.

The error i recieve is this:

```
Exception Description: Problem compiling [SELECT o FROM Bil o WHERE o.kontornr = ?1]. 
[26, 36] The state field path 'o.kontornr' cannot be resolved to a valid type.


@Entity
public class Bil {
@Id
private String regNr;
private String merke;           
private String modell;          
private String farge;           
private char gruppe;            
private boolean ledig;          
private int kontorNr;
```

Comment: Show us the code of the Bil entity. JPQL works with entities and their fields, not with tables and their columns.

Comment: There, that is really all I've done there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field is declared as

```
private int kontorNr;
```

The query is

```
SELECT o FROM Bil o WHERE o.kontornr = ?1
```

Java is case sensitive. `kontronr != kontorNr`.